# Validate date fromat with timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to validate the date(2022-08-28T14:35:02.439Z) given in this format, If i try to change the format it should throw error as invalid.

I have checked with below code, it is retruning IST time zone

```
function convertUTCtoCDT() {
    var timelagging = -6; // 5 or 6
    var utc = new Date();
    var cdt = new Date(utc.getTime()-((1 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * timelagging));
    console.log("CDT: "+cdt);
}
```

Any reference to validate whether the date format is valid 2022-08-28T14:35:02.439Z or not if i have changed the format to something else

Comment: Check out the `timezone` plugin for momentjs (https://momentjs.com/timezone/). You can easily change the timezone with this plugin.

Comment: @beeef there is no need to add a dependency on momentjs. One can achieve this by using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica you're right, thank you. I just recommended that because the question is tagged with `momentjs`. Your solution is better, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The format you are mentioning is the ISO format:

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString())
```

I suggest having a look at the new `Intl.DateTimeFormat` API and handle the timezone only on client side when you need to display it, otherwise I would keep the DateTime in UTC (backend or in some calculations):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat